# Design - Progress bar in WCF Streaming upload

Tags: c#, wcf, file-upload, progress-bar

We have a requirement in our project to display the user with a progress bar on file upload to server.

For file upload, we are using steaming mode in WCF.

After initiating file upload, a new thread will make another request to server to the get the uploaded file status. On the Server, the file being uploaded is opened in *shared read mode* and returned the file length to client. Based on this return value, the progress bar is updated.

We are polling the server every 2 seconds to get the uploaded file length. Is this a proper design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not uncommon, but if you are looking for a *cleaner* way to do this (avoiding polling is always a good idea) you could of course actively notify the program when the progress changes (e.g. every 1% or 10%), by using a [duplex-contract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731184%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to report the current progress.